# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element error in Python selenium even though ID and name are present in HTML

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried to select radio button in selenium python using by_id, by_name but getting error message as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".radio_1"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
```

I have tried `element_by_id()`, `element_by_name()`

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://iiiindia.org.in/app#/auth')
aa= driver.find_element_by_id('radio_1').click()
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "md-radio-button#radio_1"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//md-radio-button[@id='radio_1']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: iiiindia]

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Answer (score 1):

Before clicking the radio button, you need to wait for it to be ready (clickable):

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "radio_1")).click()
```